# Copy and Unzip function works, until it is called from another function?

Tags: php

I have a function called `fileGet`, its purpose is simple:

1. Download a file from a given URL.
2. Unzip said File.
3. Launch the File Formatting function.

It does all of these things perfectly fine, however when I call it from another function it stops working?

When it is run from another function (which used to work perfectly fine) I get thrown out an empty zip with no unzipped file.

This then throws out errors later in the program, when it attempts to use the file that is not there.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: The Directory structure is as follows:

MainFolder [php[ThisCode], json[zip & json file]]

I hope this helps?

```
function fileGet(){
  $extURL = 'exampleURL';
  $path = "../json/AllSets.json.zip";
  copy($extURL, $path);
  $newZip = new ZipArchive();
  if ($newZip->open('../json/AllSets.json.zip') == TRUE) {
    $newZip->extractTo('../json/');
    $newZip->close();
  }
}

function fileArch(){
  $today = date("d-m-Y");
  if (file_exists('../json/archive/'.$today.'.zip') == FALSE){
    $zip = new ZipArchive();
    $zip->open('../json/archive/'.$today.'.zip', ZipArchive::CREATE);
    $zip->addFile('../json/AllSetsLess.json', 'AllSetsLess.json');
    $zip->close();
    unlink('../json/AllSets.json');
    unlink('../json/AllSets.json.zip');
    unlink('../json/AllSetsLess.json');
    fileGet();
  }
}

function fileCompare(){
  stream_context_set_default(
    array(
      'http' => array(
        'method' => 'HEAD'
      )
    )
  );
  $extURL = get_headers("exampleURL")[3];
  $extURL = (int)preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", '', $extURL);
  $intURL = filesize("../json/AllSets.json.zip");
  echo('external: '.$extURL.' internal: '.$intURL);
  if ($extURL !== $intURL) {
    echo('Launching Download');
    fileArch();
  }
}

fileCompare();
```

I expect a zip file and json file in my json folder, but simply get a zip file with a filesize of 0.

Edit: I tried a few different things, including removing the if statement from `fileArch()` and playing around with the `relative` or `absolute` linking, but for now I am totally stumped, the `fileGet()` function works fine if you call it on its own, but when it is called from one of the other functions it simply does not work.

Edit2: So if I start the program from `fileArch()` then it works fine, I think maybe something is left open in `fileCompare()` ? I cannot find anything that has been left open though, and the variables should all be local. I know that `fileCompare()` is loading `fileArch()` because it deletes the files just fine, but there seems to be some sort of conflict that I cannot see between `fileCompare()` and `fileGet()` . If you have any idea what this could be please let me know as PHP is not my first language.

Edit 3: I have located the conflict but have no idea why it is conflicting. So the issue was the code:

```
 stream_context_set_default(
    array(
      'http' => array(
        'method' => 'HEAD'
      )
    )
  );
```

In the `fileCompare()` function, I need this code to allow the server to check the headers of the other server from what I remember so can anyone tell me why this is causing the conflict?

Comment: does the default working dir same for the second function? Is the value of $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] same as the working scenario?

Comment: I don't know whether it's web or cli app or how you are calling but check `get_headers()` if you are calling in cli mode

Comment: Where is this code located? You're copying the file to `$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/json/AllSets.json.zip";`, so to a folder called `json` under the document root, but then all other references use `../json`. This will work if and only if this script is one level below the document root.

Comment: Ivanov yes its exactly the same, I tried out $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']  to see if it made any improvements, but it was exactly the same either way.

Comment: Greg Schmidt I have editted with the structure, but I have 2 folders in my root directory, php; which contains this code, and json; which contains the data files I am using. the  $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] was a test to see if it solved the problem, it made no difference from what I could tell, I should have removed it before posting, my bad.

Comment: Viney It is web, but I will triple check my usage of get_headers just in case.

Answer (score 0):

```
stream_context_set_default(
    array(
      'http' => array(
        'method' => 'HEAD'
      )
    )
  );
```

So this was the code that was causing problems, perhaps it was interfering with the copy request because the get requests has been turned into head requests? 
I got the code from the PHP manual [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-set-default.php) , so if anyone else is having some issues with copy requests then check if you have changed the stream_context at all. I will have a read up on how stream_context is supposed to be used and write back here when I have something more substantial.